# setxattr fails with Operation not supported

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to set the file attributes as follows:

1. create file foo.txt with 0644 permissions
2. when I am trying to setxattr for this as

   ```
   if (setxattr("foo.txt", "user.test", "test", 4, XATTR_CREATE) == -1)
       perror("");
   ```

I am getting the error as Operation not supported

Is there any thing to enable?
How to resolve this?

Comment: Does your filesystem support it? Remounting with `user_xattr` mount option may help.

Comment: Which filesystem are you using?

Comment: I am using nfs filesystem

Answer (score 5):

From [`setxattr`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/lsetxattr.2.html)

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> ```
>    On success, zero is returned.  On failure, -1 is returned and errno is set
>    appropriately.  
>    ...  
>    If extended attributes are not supported by the file system, or are disabled,
>    errno is set to ENOTSUP.
> ```

So, either your file system doesn't support extended attributes (ext[234], cifs, btrfs do, for example) or they are disabled at the kernel build or at mount time.

For NFS there is no separate switch to enable extended attributes in the kernel config. From the source `fs/nfs/dir.c`, it seems to be enabled, when you enable support for `CONFIG_NFS_V3` or `CONFIG_NFS_V4`. But NFS still depends on the underlying file system. So you must enable extended attributes on the server side as well.

From [`man mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

> **Mount options for ext2**
>   ...
>   **user_xattr|nouser_xattr**
>   Support "user." extended attributes (or not).

Comment: How to enable the extended attributes for nfs file system in Linux kernel?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Search for `xattr` in `fs/nfs*/*.c`.

Comment: It seems Linux [doesn't support](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.nfs/53259) extended attributes on NFS.

Comment: I am on ext4 and also not supported, so extended attributes are disabled by default?

Comment: @kensai According to [fs/ext4/Makefile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/ext4/Makefile) (`ext4-y := ... xattr.o ...`), I would expect it is always compiled in for `ext4`. But maybe the file system is mounted with some option disabling it, e.g. `nouser_xattr` or something else.

Comment: @OlafDietsche my / is mounted as /dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered) and tmp where compilation is done tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,noatime,size=16777216k). Will look at this in more detail..

Comment: @kensai This looks, like it should work. I have no further idea, sorry. Maybe, ask a new question, so someone else can look into this. Also, Superuser or Unix & Linux might be a good place to ask.

Comment: Only from NFSv4 there is support for acl, and they are bit different.